# Azure Automation job activation failing

Tags: azure-automation

I'm attempting to execute a PowerShell workflow in Azure Automation on a Hybrid Worker. No matter what I try I get the following error:

> The job action 'Activate' cannot be run, because the process stopped
>   unexpectedly. The job action was attempted 3 times.

- The workflow works on an Azure Worker (just not on Hybrid Worker)
- The workflow includes only a `get-date`command
- Tried using run-as credentials on the Hybrid Worker
- Running a script (as opposed to workflow) works on the Hybrid Worker
- It is a new installation, it never worked before
- No events logged on the Hybrid Worker

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you're on the latest version of the hybrid worker. An easy fix to update the agent is to restart the MMA service or restart your machine.